# ¿Cómo usar event_generate en un combobox en tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, eventos, combobox, keypressevent

Tengo una interfaz en tkinter y en una de las subventanas un combobox, el cuál funciona correctamente, por ejemplo al mover la flecha de abajo del teclado es posible desplazarse entre las palabras del combobox.

Sin embargo, **quiero generar un evento que simule el presionar la flecha hacia abajo que se active con un botón de la interfaz**. Ya he generado el mismo evento en otra ocasión en una entrada de texto pero no sé porque en este caso lo único que pasa es que se cierra y se abre el combobox.

Aquí dejo lo que considero que es lo importante del código. Gracias.

```
            self.boton = Button(self.ventana, image=self.lista_imagenes_tele[4], border=0, command=self.boton_abajo)
            self.boton.config(bg="#0C0F0A", activebackground="#0C0F0A")
            self.boton.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.325)

            lista=list(directorio)

            print(lista)
            bigfont = font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=60)
            self.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Font", bigfont)
            self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self.ventana, state="readonly") #state="readonly" bloquea la escritura desde el combobox
            self.combo['values'] = lista
            self.combo.config(font=fuente)
            self.combo.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1)

        def boton_abajo(self):
            self.combo.event_generate('<Down>') 
            print("abajo")
```

Al probar lo mismo pero con el evento *Up* no pasa igual que lo anterior que abre y cierra el combobox, en este caso solamente se cierra y se queda así. También ya intenté en lugar de *self.combo* usar *self.ventana* en la función y tampoco funciona. Agradezco cualquier idea.